# Problem with Terraform erroring on resource creation because of a missing referenced attribute that will be created

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I desire to add a Key Vault access policy for an App Service which will use the App Services managed identity. If I add the required identity attribute as type "System Assigned" to the App Service and the Key Vault access policy referencing the "to be" created object id for the managed identity of the existing App Service, I get an error during plan/apply stating that "The argument "object_id" is required, but no definition was found.".
Code example:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "webapp1" {
  name                = "app-web-myapp-test3"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.secondary_rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.secondary_rg.location
  service_plan_id     = data.terraform_remote_state.shared_resources.outputs.primary_plan_id
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  site_config {
    always_on = false
  }
}


resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "secondary_policy" {
  key_vault_id = data.terraform_remote_state.shared_resources.outputs.primary_vault_id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id          = azurerm_linux_web_app.webapp1.identity.0.principal_id
  secret_permissions = ["Get", ]
     depends_on = [
      azurerm_linux_web_app.webapp1
     ]
}
```

Using a depends on for the App Service doesn't help because the resource already exists (but not the required attribute) and thus fails. Depends on does not permit itself to be used on an attribute, only the resource.
If I first apply the managed identity change to the app service and then after completion, add the Key Vault policy, it works fine. If I run it from scratch before the App Service is create, it waits for the App Service to be created with the managed identity, and works fine.
However, I want to keep the App Service in place and apply these changes during the same apply.
How can this dependency be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This workaround also works for web apps: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/19316

Essentially, referencing a data source rather than the resource directly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies in Terraform are only for deciding what order to take actions in, and not to decide what actions will actually be taken. In your situation it sounds like this isn't a problem of dependencies but rather a problem of an unsupported configuration.

Terraform will first ask the `hashicorp/azurerm` provider to plan changes to `azurerm_linux_web_app.webapp1`, and then use the values from that result to populate the configuration for `azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.secondary_policy`.

In order for the second resource's configuration to be valid, the plan for the first resource must include a non-null value in `.identity[0].principal_id`. Your configuration doesn't set `principal_id`, and apparently the provider doesn't insert any default value for it, so the result isn't valid.

One way to make this work would be for you to explicitly set `principal_id` inside the `identity`, in which case the reference will return the same value.

---

Unfortunately I think there seems to be some missing logic in the provider to properly handle the case where the `principal_id` is decided by the remote system rather than by your configuration.

If I'm understanding correctly the way these features are supposed to work, I think the provider ought to set the `principal_id` attribute to `(known after apply)` during the planning phase if it intends to populate it with a real value during the apply phase. That would then allow the downstream resource to see that `principal_id` is going to have a value during apply and so avoid raising this validation error.

There is no way to fix that missing logic by changing your Terraform code, unless you can specify an explicit `principal_id` in your configuration. It is the provider's responsibility to describe the planned final state of a resource during the planning phase, and if the provider doesn't return a correct answer to that question then downstream actions will be acting on incorrect information and so can fail like you saw here. If this is the case for you then I think the best thing to do next is to open an issue about it in [the `hashicorp/azurerm` provider repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm), so that the provider team can investigate why the provider is not setting this attribute correctly during planning.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, this seems logical. I went ahead and opened up a github issue.